# Undefined method 'permit' for "89718":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, serialization

I'm writing a simple Rails api that connects to a legacy SQL Server database. I am testing my REST actions for my contacts controller. When using FactoryGirl to create test objects, I ran into the error message mentioned in the title. My index and show actions work fine, but the create action is throwing this error. The relevant parts of my contacts_controller look like this:

```
def create
    contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if contact.save
        render json: contact, status: 201, location: [:api, contact]
    else
        render json: { errors: contact.errors }, status: 422
    end
end
...
private
    def contact_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :address_1, :city, :zip_code_5, :country)
    end
```

And here is the relevant test code:

```
describe "POST #create" do
    context "when is successfully created" do
        before(:each) do
            @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
            @contact = FactoryGirl.create :contact
            post :create, { contact: @contact }
        end

        it "renders the json representation for the contact record just created" do
            contact_response = json_response
            expect(contact_response[:name]).to eq @contact_attributes[:name]
        end

        it { should respond_with 201 }
    end
end
```

The model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    validates :name, :address_1, :city, :zip_code_5, :country, :createddate, presence: true
end
```

The serializer (using the active_model_serializer gem):

```
class ContactSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    belongs_to :user
    attributes :id, :name, :address_1, :city, :zip_code_5, :country
end
```

Things I've tried include:

- Changing the 'belongs_to' to 'has_one' in the serializer (no change)
- Removing the 'zip_code_5' from the permite...require line (strangely, I still got the error message about this property, perhaps because of the serializer?)
- Removing the serializer (no change)

Any thoughts? I'm happy to provide any more necessary information.

EDIT

The value of @contact when it's passed to the create action:

```
#<Contact id: 89815, user_id: "d67b0d57-8f7f-4854-95b5-f07105741fa8", title: nil, firstname: nil, lastname: nil, name: "Alene Stark", company: nil, address_1: "72885 Bauch Island", address_2: nil, address_3: nil, city: "Joestad", state: nil, zip_code_5: "98117", zip_code_4: nil, country: "MF", status_id: 1, createddate: "2015-10-23 07:00:00", lastmodifieddate: "2012-11-29 08:00:00", errorreasonid: nil, computergenerated: true, sandbox: true, emailsubject: nil, jobtitle: nil, mergevar1: nil, mergevar2: nil, mergevar3: nil, mergevar4: nil, mergevar5: nil, mergevar6: nil, mergevar7: nil, mergevar8: nil, mergevar9: nil, mergevar10: nil, clientid: 1, isshared: true>
```

The value of params[:contact] at runtime:

```
{"city"=>"Seattle", "state"=>"WA", "zip_code_5"=>"98117", "country"=>"US"}
```

I also have my wrap parameters set to :json format, if that's relevant.

Comment: for some reason your `params[:contact]` in the controller is a string. Can you check the value of `@contact` that you're passing to post? Also maybe check the value of `params[:contact]` at runtime and show what that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the console to recreate what my test was doing. I discovered that Contact was being passed as a string, instead of a hash. After a little Googling, I passed the @contact object as @contact.attributes, which passes a hash of the object. This solved the 'permit' problem, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.